# ASP NET 6 Passing HtmlContent to helper/function

Tags: razor, .net-6.0

I have an MVC5 app which I'm porting to .NET 6. Previously, we used an HTML helper which allowed us to pass some HTML and return a button type thing with the passed HTML used as part of the rendered output. Ie:

```
@helper InfoRow(string title, Func<dynamic, HelperResult> content)
{
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">@title</label>
        <div class="col">
            <span class="form-control-plaintext">
                @content(null)
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Called using

```
 @InfoRow("Notes", @<span><b>@row.Number</b> new notes</span>)
```

I've ben changing helpers to functions in .NET 6 but am a little stuck on this one as I can't find any examples of passing HTML t a function. Is it possible?

So far I have this:

```
@functions {
    private void InfoRow(string title, IHtmlContent content)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">@title</label>
            <div class="col">
                <span class="form-control-plaintext">
                    @content
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this working example. I hope it helps you:

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    }


    @functions{
        void InfoRow(string title, Func<dynamic, HelperResult> content)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">@title</label>
                <div class="col">
                    <span class="form-control-plaintext">
                        @content(string.Empty)
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    }


    @{
        InfoRow("Test title",@<span> @ViewData["Title"]</span>);
    }
```